# Timeout on connect to socket using NIO SocketChannel

Tags: java, nio

We have a class that is talking to another HOST over a socket and it looks like this:

```
SocketChannel sc = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress(HOST, PORT));
sc.configureBlocking(true);

...
sc.write(...)
sc.read(...)
```

This class works great except if the HOST is down then SocketChannel.open blocks forever. I've tried to make this timeout by doing the following:

```
SocketChannel  = SocketChannel.open();
sc.configureBlocking(false);
boolean result = socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(HOST, PORT));
if (!result) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (!socketChannel.finishConnect()) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime< 1000) {
            // keep trying
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } else {
            // FAILED!
            enabled = false;
            return;
        }
    }
}
// SUCCESS!
socketChannel.configureBlocking(true);
enabled = true
```

Well for some reason finishConnect() is blocking forever when I would have expected it to not block at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Blocking is the default behaviour for NIO so you don't need to set it BTW, even if most assume it's about non blocking IO.  AFAIK you can't  change the blocking mode.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Of course you can. That's what 'configureBlocking()' is for.

Comment: @EJP Thank you for the correction.  I haven't seen it used in one block and later switched to another before.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes you have. Every channel starts out in blocking mode, so every program that uses Selectors exhibits changing to non-blocking mode. I don't understand your issue.

Answer (score 5):

You're doing this wrong.

1. Create an unconnected `SocketChannel` and do a timed connect in blocking mode.

OR

2. Use a `Selector` in non-blocking mode. Register the channel for `OP_CONNECT` and select. When it becomes connectable, call `finishConnect(),` and if it returns true deregister `OP_CONNECT` and proceed with the I/O. If it returns false, keep selecting. If it throws an exception, give up of the connection, it has failed. Use the select timeout. Not a spin loop.

Comment: BTW Can you change the blocking mode safely?

Comment: Thanks. Can someone explain what "timed connect in blocking mode means" Do you mean doing a blocking connect in another thread and waiting on that thread to finish or not?

Comment: No. A timed connect in blocking mode is done via the [`Socket.connect(endpoint, timeout)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect(java.net.SocketAddress,%20int)) method.

Comment: @EJP any way to make "timed connect" work with `SocketChannel` not plain old `Socket`?

Comment: @om-nom-nom Yes, call `channel.socket().connect(...).`