# How to set timeout when connect with Java NIO non-blocking socket?

Tags: java, sockets, nio, nonblocking

I want to set connection timeout.

I found some solutions, but every answer was read or write timeout.

and below is my code.

```
InetSocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);//set socket address
selector = Selector.open();
socketChannel = SocketChannel.open(socketAddress);//default connect timeout is 20sec
socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
socketChannel.register(selector,  SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

I want to set timeout at 'SocketChannel.open(socketAddress)'.

What can I do for it?

Comment: It seems the connection timeout is for blocking mode only: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369146/timeout-on-connect-to-socket-using-nio-socketchannel

Comment: Create the SocketChannel with the no-arg open method, configure it to non-blocking, invoke connect. If connect returns false then the connection is not established immediately, in which case you register it with the Selector for op OP_CONNECT, then call select with the timeout you want. Yes, it is a bit complicated but that is because the channels API is a low-level/advanced API. The alternative is of course to use the socket adaptor, meaning create with the no-arg open method, then invoke socketChannel.socket().connect(...) to connect with a timeout

Comment: is connection timeout blocking mode only?I think I have to find it